Structure of automorphism groups of positive ternary quadratic forms
Let $f(x,y,z)=ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2ryz+2sxz+2txy$ be a positive definite integral ternary quadratic form (in Gauss's or Dickson's sense). Let $A(f)$ be its coefficient matrix in the usual sense. Then recall that $\operatorname{Aut}^+(f)=\{T\in SL_3(\mathbb{Z}): T^tA(f)T=A(f)\}$. We know that the cardinality $|\operatorname{Aut}^+(f)| \in \{1,2,4,6,8,12,24\}$. My question is, do we know the list of the structures of the groups $\operatorname{Aut}^+(f)$?

By using the complete list of all finite subgroups of $\operatorname{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$ (e.g. Ihara's paper, namely "On the finite subgroups of $\operatorname{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$", it seems that one can say something about the structures of the groups what I asked above. Moreover, by using Dickson's book, namely "Studies in Number Theory", pages 179. and 180., it seems that one can eliminate some groups given in Ihara's paper. Anyways, I am still wondering whether there is a precise reference to answer my question or another (more conceptual) way to give the list.

If $G$ is such a group, and $B$ is some symmetric (positive definite) matrix, then
$$A:=\sum_{g\in G}g^tBg$$ should be invariant under $G$. Of course, that form may be invariant under an even bigger group for all choices of $B$.
